# Listing the contents of a ZIP file

Tags: batch-file, zip, 7zip

Following an example of tech-recipes I have managed to list the contents of a ZIP file (using 7-Zip:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s *.zip') do (7z.exe l -r "%%A" >> listing.txt)
```

However, this just dumps out the entire directory structure of the ZIP file into a text file (called listing.txt).

I only want to list the directory names of the highest level directories e.g.

Example.Zip

```
7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Listing archive: C:\Users\Test\Desktop\7zip\Demo.zip

--
Path = C:\Users\Test\Desktop\7zip\Demo.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 1252

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-04-24 13:12:26 D....            0            0  Directory Three\Sub Folder One
2013-04-24 13:13:00 D....            0            0  Directory Three\Sub Folder Three
2013-04-24 13:12:54 D....            0            0  Directory Three\Sub Folder Two
2013-04-24 13:12:26 D....            0            0  Directory Two\Sub Folder One
2013-04-24 13:13:00 D....            0            0  Directory Two\Sub Folder Three
2013-04-24 13:12:54 D....            0            0  Directory Two\Sub Folder Two
2013-04-24 13:12:26 D....            0            0  Directory One\Sub Folder One
2013-04-24 13:13:00 D....            0            0  Directory One\Sub Folder Three
2013-04-24 13:12:54 D....            0            0  Directory One\Sub Folder Two
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                                     0            0  0 files, 9 folders
```

I would only want the text file to contain:

- Directory One
- Directory Two
- Directory Three

Can anyone suggest how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

7z doesn't seem to have builtin key for this, however you can do some batch scripting (this one searches for slash in file name and displays line if slash not found) :

```
7z.exe l -r archive.zip > lines.txt

@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (lines.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  set srch=!line:\=!
  if "!line!" == "!srch!" (
     echo !line!
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
7z.exe l -r "File.7z" | FINDSTR "[0-9].D....\>" | FIND /V "\"
```

With the first Findstr we filter the output getting a list of only dirs ("D" attribute).

With the second find we delete from the output the paths containing backslashes (Folder\Subfolder).

**How to use it with a amount of zips:**

```
@echo off

(For /R %%# in (*.zip) do (

    Echo File: "%%#" | MORE

    For /F "Tokens=5,*" %%A in (
        '7z.exe l -r "%%#" ^| FINDSTR "[0-9].D....\>" ^| FIND /V "\"'
    ) do (
        Set /A "Num+=1"
        Call Echo %%NUM%%.0: %%B
    )

    Set /A "Num=0"
    Echo+

))>"listing.txt"

Pause&Exit
```

**Tested structure:**

```
   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-04-24 13:02:29 ....A          274          167  ..bat
2013-04-24 13:02:29 ....A          274               1\2\2.bat
2013-04-24 13:02:29 ....A          274               a\b\c\c.bat
2013-04-24 13:12:45 D....            0            0  a\b\c
2013-04-24 13:12:37 D....            0            0  a\b
2013-04-24 13:12:33 D....            0            0  a
2013-04-24 13:12:50 D....            0            0  1\2
2013-04-24 13:12:24 D....            0            0  1
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                                   822          167  3 files, 5 folders
```

**Output received:**

```
File: "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\x.7z" 

1.0: a
2.0: 1
```

Comment: When I run the batch file - I get a text file containing 'File: "{filename}.zip". Can you tell me about the significance of '5' for tokens?

Comment: The script runs good and prints the filanames good, please explain the filename problem with another example to understand it. A token is a string delimitted by a {space} (By default), so with "5,*" tokens we are spliting each line in 5+1 strings. 6 tokens 'cause 6 columns, one: **2013-04-24** two: **13:12:24** three: **D....** four: **0** five: **0** six: **{Folder name}**. then I print the sixth token to the textfile.

Comment: For some reason by 'raw output' does not have a 'Date' or 'Time' - would this be causing the issue?

Comment: If date or time values are empty spaces then yes that's the problem. I suppossed all the values on date/time columns ever would be filled. splitting the lines is the best choice but have that inconvenient... let me think about it.

Comment: But that example has date and time values or maybe I understanded bad what you will said? if the problem is you don't want the first folder name "demo" then you maybe will consider to compress and unchecking the option "preserve directory root" in 7zip, then "demo" root will not appear more when listing and the script will run ok.

Comment: I have updated the structure of the ZIP as suggested - I am still just getting File: "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\7zip\Demo.zip". Maybe its an issue with my version of 7-Zip.