# How to look at the contents of a zipped folder in batch?

Tags: batch-file

In this case, I have a zip folder with contents inside. How would I look into the zip folder and be able to check the file name of those files for a certain word without having to unzip the file to begin with?

So for example:
I have a zip folder with the files inside named

```
123456789COW.txt
123445614COW.txt
123456789ASK.txt
232436787CAT.txt
```

and I want to check if the file has COW inside the name. 
Every solution I have found so far has assumed I know the contents already, but in my case that may not always be true and I need to check.

Comment: Usually it's done via an external utility like 7zip. Is it acceptable for you? Otherwise take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili)

Comment: Using 7zip would be fine, but I just want to be able to run a for loop to check whether the zipped file has COW in the name so I can say "yes, it does have the file present".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listing the contents of a ZIP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188135/listing-the-contents-of-a-zip-file)